# Access system audio in UWP App

Tags: windows, audio, uwp, universal

I would like to write an app that

1. accesses the audio by being played by the user in another app
2. analyzes that audio
3. displays the analysis to the user

however, I have not found anything that makes this seem possible.  Can apps access access the audio being played through the user's speakers as a byte stream or is this not built into the API?

Comment: Please clarify by how you want the app to access audio.  Do you mean capturing audio via mic like Shazaam does?  Or are you referring to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can apps access access the audio being played through the user's
>   speakers as a byte stream or is this not built into the API?

You can do that([Loopback recording](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316551(v=vs.85).aspx)), but you need to program with low level APIs - [WASAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371455(v=vs.85).aspx). For available APIs for UWP, check the Core Audio part in [Win32 and COM for Windows Runtime apps and Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps (multimedia)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452756.aspx)

Here is an old [article](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/05/15/real-time-audio-in-windows-store-and-windows-phone-apps/) for 8.1 app, but it still applies to UWP on concept level. And Microsoft has provided a [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/93bdfb92b3da76f2e49c959807fc5643bf0940c9/Samples/WindowsAudioSession) on GitHub about WASAPI and Core Audio API, which may help you to familiar with the APIs and understand how to make it work in UWP app.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `MediaCapture` class to capture audio.  [link to docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: This is for capturing from a capture device, such as a webcam.